# GZip html response of my servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, web

I have a website and I want to compress the html response(not file, the html text) in order to improve the page latencies. Currently my html response is 12KB text would compressing it makes any sense to reduce the page load time ?

We use servlets internally to render the content, what changes should i make to the servlet code in order to serve zip content.

I have put the following code but it did not work.
        response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

```
    GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
    writer.println("<h3> Hello World </h3>");

    out.close();
```

Comment: "it did not work" how did it not work?

Comment: I mean the "hello world" text did not appear in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure you server to compress all (or curtain types) of responses.
for example, here is what you do for tomcat in server.xml file:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    compression="on"
    compressionMinSize="2048"
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"/>
```

specs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/